# Realtime Firebase get child inside another child using website js

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

Hi How can I retrieve data age from Realtime Firebase using JavaScript . 
path like this : users -> random unique key -> MyProgram -> random unique key  -> Age .

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQVhj.jpg)    [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrAwW.jpg)

My code :  it will get duplicate data twice

```
var Ref = firebase.database().ref('Users/');
 Ref.once("value", function(snashot) {
 snashot.forEach(function(chil) {

   var uu = firebase.database().ref('Users/'+chil.key+'/MyPrograms/');  

   uu.once("value", function(s){
    s.forEach(function(ss) {
   console.log(ss.val().age);});
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? You should do some research before asking on SO - and include what research you've done in your question

Comment: Also - Are you using Firestore or Realtime Database? Please update your question and the tags to reflect.

Comment: OK i will update